# How to convert the following ssh command to autossh?

Tags: ssh, autossh

My ssh code works fine. But after a while it timed out and shut down, so I thought of switching to autossh. But when I tried the same code in autossh, it doesn't work. How can I adapt this code to autossh?
My ssh code:
`ssh -R443:localhost:443 remote.moe`

I am using this code to get api from local computer using apache and get the API via a url.

I'm tried `autossh -R443:localhost:443 remote.moe` but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on thismyself, but try adding the options:
`-M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 5" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3"`
Hope this helps.